# Translation of Vishnu Dharma Purana

Tags: vishnu, translation-request, resource, upapuranas

Viṣṇu dharma purāṇa is one of the [18 upa purāṇas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upapurana#The_Brihadddharma_Purana_list). This text is available in Sanskrit online. Is it available in English or Hindi or any other Indian language?

Comment: I didn't find any other languages. But in Telugu it is translated by Kalluri Venkata Subrahmanya Dikshitulu Garu. The text is available at http://www.kamakoti.org/telugu2/ . The book numbers are 61 and 64.
If you want to buy, English Version is here http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/visnudharmottara-purana-3-volumes-IDF396/

Comment: The first part of Kalluri's translation in Telugu is available at http://www.dli.ernet.in/handle/2015/395895

Comment: @student. Thanks for your effort. But Vishnu Dharma and Vishnu Dharmottara purana are different puranas.

Comment: Oh, I donot know. Can you point me the sanskrit text of this purana online

Comment: @Student http://www.astrojyoti.com/pdfs/DevanagariFiles/vishnudharma_purana.pdf  ---- This is the pdf link for VIshnu dharma purana in sanskrit.